# Can't get user confirmation to work in production with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I've been trying to debug this all day but getting nowhere. Basically I have the confirmable module in my user model. It sends the confirmation link just fine but when I click the link in the email, it takes me to my home page and does nothing. It works perfectly fine in dev. Here are my settings in my prod configs:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mysite.com' }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: 587,
  user_name: ENV['SES_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SES_PASSWORD'],
  authentication: :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

The confirmation token param in the link does in fact match the token saved to the user object. Not sure what to look for in my logs at this point. There aren't any errors coming up. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try setting ```https://my_site.com``` to your host. Also, I don't see a ```domain``` in your ```smtp_settings```.  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806298/devise-confirm-link-redirects-user-to-heroku-domain-not-a-custom-domain

Comment: You should find more useful information from log file as well as flash message if you have set it up. From log file, you'll know if the request reach the correct controller or not, from the flash message you know if the confirmation is success or not.